# Log 4j Html Layout

Tags: log4j

I am using log4j (HTML Layout) the file does not get rolled over everyday for the below log4j.xml. I am using log4j extras. If I use log into a simple log file it works fine but does not work for a html layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>
    <!-- Daily Rolling File Appender that compresses old files -->
    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender" >
        <param name="threshold" value="info"/>
        <rollingPolicy name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="${catalina.home}/ApplicationLogs/ApplicationLogs-%d{yyyy-mm-dd}.html"/>
            <param name="ActiveFileName" value="${catalina.home}/ApplicationLogs/ApplicationLogs.html"/>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout" >
            <param name="LocationInfo" value="true" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
         <priority value="debug"></priority>
         <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```